# Scrapy contextfactory.py. NameError in iPython. Trying to used twisted library

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted

I am trying to run a fetch command in scrapy shell. The error points to contextfactory.py. The twisted library is already included in my virtual environment. How do I resolve this error?

```
from twisted.internet.ssl import ClientContextFactory
from twisted.internet.ssl import PrivateCertificate 



myClientCert = twisted.internet.ssl.PrivateCertificate.load(keyAndCert.read())
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from twisted.internet.ssl import ClientContextFactory
from twisted.internet.ssl import PrivateCertificate 

myClientCert = twisted.internet.ssl.PrivateCertificate.load(keyAndCert.read())
```

Line 1 puts the `ClientContextFactory` name into your scope.  Line 2 puts the `PrivateCertificate` name into your scope.  Line 4 tries to read two names from your scope: `twisted` and `keyAndCert`.  Neither of these match the two names you have put in your scope (`ClientContextFacotry` and `PrivateCertificate`).

Fortunately, the reason you are trying to use the `twisted` name, apparently, is to reach `PrivateCertificate`.  You can replace `twisted.internet.ssl.PrivateCertificate` with the name that is actually in your scope, `PrivateCertificate`.

Once you fix this, you'll get an error about `keyAndCert` since that is also not defined in your scope (unless it really is but you've omitted the code that defines it).

Comment: i actually have the definition for keyAndCert

with open ('C:\\Users\\PENunez\\Anaconda\\envs\\scrapy_demo\\Lib\\site-packages\\scrapy\\core\\downloader\\panasia04.pem') as keyAndCert

Comment: so i should use myClientCert = PrivateCertificate.load(keyAndCert.read()) instead right? thank you

Comment: by replacing twisted.internet.ssl.PrivateCertificate to PrivateCertificate, i was able to make it work but now i get a different error

TypeError: load() missing 1 required positional argument: 'privateKey'

is privateKey a file path? if not, what should i put in the argument?